# Redux middleware to handle asynchronous actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is middleware in react-redux - what does it do and when should I use it?

Comment: jonrsharpe whats you mean by  asynchronous actions please explain

Comment: Async actions are all actions  which needs time to be finished like requests to db for example,or requests to some API-s for data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`.